# http.HandleFunc not executing function on rpi golang

Tags: go

For a project, I have been working on a webserver in Go.
When I run it on my laptop everything works fine, but when I try to run it on the raspberry pi 3b+ (compiled on my laptop with the command `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build .`), it won't execute the counter function when I go to the server.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "webcam_server/subdir"
    "webcam_server/websocket"
)

var ConnImg net.Conn
var ConnData net.Conn

func counter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("connected")
    ws, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v\n", err)
    }


    go websocket.Writer(ws, ConnImg)
    go websocket.Writer2(ws, ConnData) //start counter and send count to the webserver
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Simple counter")
    host := ":4444"
    fmt.Println("Capturing. Open http://localhost" + host)

    go subdir.Start_tcp_conn_images(&ConnImg)
    go subdir.Start_tcp_conn_data(&ConnData)
    //go subdir.InitializeDatabase()
    //start the counter function
    http.HandleFunc("/data", counter) 

    //link index.html to webaddress
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
        t.Execute(w, "index")
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(host, nil))
}
```

I am a bit confused about why counter runs when I go to the URL: http://localhost:4444 on my laptop, but not on the raspberry pi (when I visit rpi_ip:4444).

Comment: What is the import `"webcam_server/websocket"`?

Comment: That is a directory that contains other functions like the writer functions

Comment: What shows up when you `curl -Is localhost:4444` on the raspberry?

Comment: Your example doesn't include anything actually executing the `counter` function. Please try submitting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are correct I changed the code and uploaded the wrong one. I changed it.

Comment: When I curl, I get :`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 15:03:33 GMT
Content-Length: 1357
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Can you include the actual response you get when you attempt this request?

Comment: What do you mean with actual respons and this request?